# Regex folder redirection containing same name (creating loop)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to create a regex expression to redirect a folder and it's contents, but am creating a redirect loop as the new folder starts with the same word.
I'm actually putting this in the 'Redirection' Wordpress plugin, but hopefully should be same as mod_rewrite RewriteRule statements.

Intention:

```
FROM:   /photo  OR      /photo/   OR    /photo/anything/    
TO:     /photo-video    /photo-video/   /photo-video/anything/
```

Using:

```
/photo(.*) /photo-video$1     -> creates a redirect loop (keeps adding '-video')
/photo/(.*) /photo-video/$1   -> misses out the case without trailing /
```

I feel like after `/photo` I need to create a condition of: `[ '/' followed by (.*) ] OR [ nothing ]` (i.e. won't match if further characters before a `/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this in regex:

**FROM:** `^/photo(/.*|$)`
**TO:**   `/photo-video$1`

```
/photo           -> /photo-video
/photo/          -> /photo-video/
/photo/anything  -> /photo-video/anything
/photo/anything/ -> /photo-video/anything/
```

Breaking this down for you:

`^/photo(/.*|$)`

- Beginning of string `^`
- Followed by `/photo`
- Followed by `/` and anything else; i.e., `/.*`

  - Or, followed by end of string (nothing) `$`

Comment: Ah, of course, I had got close but not quite got the syntax!  As a regex newbie I love the beauty of it.  (Thanks very much for the clear explanation - this has solved for me but am unable to publicly upvote)